# Laravel 5.1 user profile link

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Okey, so i creating a link to user profile. My controller looks like that:

```
    public function show($id)
{
    $user = User::whereId($id)->User::whereUsername($username)->whereActivated(true)->first();

    $user->access_counter++;
    $user->save();

    $this->title($user->username);
    $this->pageView('users::show', compact('user'));
}
```

My routes file looks like that:

```
ModuleRoute::get('users/{username}', 'UsersController@show');
```

Then i going to adress: default.com/users/test, i got error: No query results for model [Models\User].

Thats the problem? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Don't you mix id with login for example? User `test` exists in your db?

Comment: Yes user exist in db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that your controller is trying to look up the users using the {id} and the route is trying to look them up using {username}.

**Solution 1:**
In your show method in the controller, try to find the users by their username and tweak the code a bit, something like this:

```
   public function show($username)
{
    $user = User::whereUsername($username)->whereActivated(true)->first();

    $user->access_counter++;
    $user->save();

    $this->title($user->username);
    $this->pageView('users::show', compact('user'));
}
```

**Solution 2:**

You could change your app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php's boot method:

```
public function boot( Router $router )
{
    parent::boot( $router );

    $router->bind( 'username',
        function ( $username )
        {
            return \App\User::where( 'username', $username )->firstOrFail( );
        }
    );
}
```

Then you can type-hint the User model as an argument in your controller's show method

```
public function show( App\User $user )
{
    return view('users.show', compact('user'));
}
```

Laravel will bind the user model with the given username automatically for you in any route you specify the `{username}` placeholder and type-hint it in the controller's method.

If you bind then you will not have to execute the findOrFail() or whereUsername() manually.

If you run into problems with changes not being committed, try doing:
`php artisan route:cache` & `php artisan optimize --force`

Comment: Thanks! Working with solution 1. I don't know why i dont think about it and do that silly mistake.